# If string does not contain any of list of strings in python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, from which I want to locate every line that has 'http://' in it, but does not have 'lulz', 'lmfao', '.png', or any other items in a list of strings in it. How would I go about this?

My instincts tell me to use regular expressions, but I have a moral objection to witchcraft.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an option that is fairly extensible if the list of strings to exclude is large:

```
exclude = ['lulz', 'lmfao', '.png']
filter_func = lambda s: 'http://' in s and not any(x in s for x in exclude)

matching_lines = filter(filter_func, string_list)
```

List comprehension alternative:

```
matching_lines = [line for line in string_list if filter_func(line)]
```

Comment: Awesome! I get to use lambda! I knew it existed for some reason!

Comment: You don't have to. `lambda` allows you to define the function inline instead of setting up a variable `filter_func`; but you could just as easily write `def filter_func(s): return 'http://' in s and not any(x in s for x in exclude)`. Remember, functions are objects.

Comment: I would even say this is an inappropriate use of `lambda`.  There is no reason to prefer it to a `def` here.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost equivalent to F.J's solution, but uses [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead of lambda expressions and the filter function:

```
haystack = ['http://blah', 'http://lulz', 'blah blah', 'http://lmfao']
exclude = ['lulz', 'lmfao', '.png']

http_strings = (s for s in haystack if s.startswith('http://'))
result_strings = (s for s in http_strings if not any(e in s for e in exclude))

print list(result_strings)
```

When I run this it prints:

```
['http://blah']
```

Comment: +1 for generators. But, note that you can do this as a(n almost) one-liner: `result_strings = [s for s in haystack if s.startswith('http://') and not any(e in s for e in exclude)]`. It needs a line break to fit 80 columns (per most style guides), but I would argue it is slightly easier to follow than the two-generator version. timeit also reports that this is a fair bit faster, and also slightly faster than F.J's filter version (which, IMO, is the hardest to follow of the three).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for s in strings:
    if 'http://' in s and not 'lulz' in s and not 'lmfao' in s and not '.png' in s:
        # found it
        pass
```

Other option, if you need your options more flexible:

```
words = ('lmfao', '.png', 'lulz')
for s in strings:
    if 'http://' in s and all(map(lambda x, y: x not in y, words, list(s * len(words))):
        # found it
        pass
```

Comment: That was my first approach. But as my list grew and the line became unwieldy, I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: That could get out of hand if he ever wanted to extend the list of stop words.  How would you change your approach?  But still, +1 for simple solutions.